# Why is there no 'position' argument in Relay+GraphQL connections?

Tags: pagination, graphql, relayjs

GraphQL and Relay has a robust pagination algorithm which enables easy pagination for the end user, allowing pagination even in unbounded and order-independent results.

However, I have a use case that I'm not really sure how to go about doing in GraphQL and relay, and it's quite easy that I'm sure I just missed something.

How do I, for example, get the 5th item (and only the 5th item), if my list is ordered (by, say, an orderBy argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not very well documented, but here's how to do it.

```
query {
  allPeople(first: 5, last: 1) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

First you select `first: 5` to get the first 5 people in the list. Then, do `last:1` which gets the last person from that *subset*. In other words - get the fifth person.

If you do `(first: 5, last: 2)` you would get the 4th and the 5th person in the list.

[**Demo**](http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/?query=query%20%7B%0A%20%20allPeople(first%3A%205%2C%20last%3A%201)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&operationName=undefined) 
*(if it returns an error - manually re-type the word `query` in the query and it will work). Then, try again without `first` and `last` to see the whole list and you'll see that Leia is 5th.*

Comment: Although this may sound like a bit of a hack, the connection spec in its current form [explicitly defines this behavior](http://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm). This is somewhat more lenient than how Facebook's original (internal) GraphQL implementation behaved, which rejects using `first` and `last` together as invalid.

Comment: @wincent, I don't follow. Can you explain? The link shows how to do it if you have a cursor. OP wants to get the N:th item without having any cursor.

Comment: Look at section 4.3: it describes the behavior both with and without cursors. Also says "Including a value for both `first` and `last` is strongly discouraged, as it is likely to lead to confusing queries and results." so caveat emptor...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ordered list at the backend and you want to get the element at a particular position, just specify the position value as an argument for the query field. The code for the query field looks like the following:

```
employee: {
  type: EmployeeType,
  args: {
    position: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
    },
    ...args,
  },
  resolve: async (context, {position, ...args}) => {
    // Get the ordered list of employees, probably from cache.
    // Pick the employee with the requested position in the list.
    // Return the employee.
  },
},
```

Comment: This is a legit approach too. A similar, common pattern is to create a `find` argument for the purposes of selecting a single item from a connection. Note also that both cursors and ids are opaque, so you can define whatever behavior and internal implementation details that you want, then use/abuse them. For example, if you wanted to implement a limit/offset based pagination model, you could bake the offset into the cursor such that you could do `first: 1 after: $cursor` type queries, generating the appropriate cursor on the fly (obviously, this breaks encapsulation, so use sparingly).